# ggsave(): Error in UseMethod("grid.draw") : no applicable method for 'grid.draw' applied to an object of class "character"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to save a plot with `ggsave()`.  I enter the following:

```
library(ggplot2)

Test = data.frame("X" = seq(1, 10, 1), "Y" = 2*seq(1, 10, 1))

P = ggplot(
    Test, aes(x=X, y=Y))+
    geom_line()

ggsave(P, "test.pdf", device = "pdf")
```

But get the error:

```
Saving 7 x 7 in image
Error in UseMethod("grid.draw") : 
  no applicable method for 'grid.draw' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Many R functions that save data, such as `write.table()`, `saveRDS()` etc. take as their first argument the object to be saved.  But, this is **not** true for `ggsave()`.  Instead, by default, its first argument is the name of the file to save to.  Thus, the syntax above would need to be modified in one of two ways:

```
ggsave(plot = P, filename = "test.pdf", device = "pdf")
ggsave("test.pdf", P, device = "pdf")
```

Comment: I have tried your solution, and I am still receiving the same error do you maybe have an idea why? I am using `ggsave('Image1.jpeg',plot=g,path='/home/theunie/Desktop/',device='jpeg')`

Comment: add the image1.jpge to the path argument.  They should all be one argument.

Comment: I think it could work even without adding the path parameter, it will automatically save to the downloads folder.