# Save a list of plots dynamically

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am able to generate some plots based on a list of data frames:

```
df1 <- mtcars
df2 <- mtcars

combined_mtcars <- list(first_df = df1, second_df = df2)

# make the plots
imap(.x = combined_mtcars, ~ggplot(.x, aes(x = hp, y = mpg, group = cyl)) +
    geom_line() +
    ggtitle(.y))
```

I wanted to then save each plot to a directory called /plots. So I tried adding ggsave like so:

```
imap(.x = combined_mtcars, ~ggplot(.x, aes(x = hp, y = mpg, group = cyl)) +
    geom_line() +
    ggtitle(.y)) %>% 
  imap(~ggsave(plot = .y, file = paste0("/plots/", .y, ".png")))
```

This resulted in error "Saving 6.62 x 5.57 in image
Error in UseMethod("grid.draw") : 
  no applicable method for 'grid.draw' applied to an object of class "character"".

How can I save each iteration where the filename is the same as the title .y?

Comment: Is `.y` the plot? `ggsave` requires the first object to be the `ggplot` object, in your example it seems to me that .y is the title. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43170744/ggsave-error-in-usemethodgrid-draw-no-applicable-method-for-grid-draw

Comment: Hi @Chabo .y is the name I would like the plot to be saved as. So no, it is not the plot itself

Comment: If you assign each iteration of creating the ggplot to say `plot<-impat(.x.....)` then you could `imap(~ggsave(plot = plot, file = paste0("/plots/", .y, ".png")))`. Since plot should be overwritten everytime, and the name of the file only depends on .y, you should be able to export each file each iteration with a new filename

Comment: Actually by using a `tag = ..` argument under the `labs()` function of ggplot, you can explicit label each graph.

Comment: Not sure what tag means but I tried this: ```imap(.x = combined_mtcars, function(i) {
  plot <- ggplot(.x, aes(x = hp, y = mpg, group = cyl) +
                   geom_line() +
                   ggtitle(.y))
  ggsave(plot, file = paste0("/plots/", .y, ".png"))
})``` which gave error "Error in .f(.x[[i]], .y[[i]], ...) : unused argument (.y[[i]])
"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to make sure the ggplot object is being passed as the first argument, using the `tag` argument in the `labs()` function allows us to assign the plot to a "variable".

```
imap(.x = combined_mtcars, ~ggplot(.x, aes(x = hp, y = mpg, group = cyl)) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(title = .y, tag="Plot")%>% 
  imap(~ggsave(plot = Plot, file = paste0("/plots/", .y, ".png")))
```

If that does not work, try this since ggsave may default to the correct plot.

```
 imap(.x = combined_mtcars, ~ggplot(.x, aes(x = hp, y = mpg, group = cyl)) +
        geom_line() +
        ggtitle(.y)) %>% 
      imap(~ggsave(file = paste0("/plots/", .y, ".png")))
```